# Fancybox v2 override/format title

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How can i override the Title in the new version of fancy box?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".photogalleryLightbox li a").fancybox({
        helpers:{ 
                    title: {
                        type: 'inside',
                        beforeShow: function(opts)
                                    {
                                        console.log('beforeShow title helper');
                                    },
                        },
                    buttons : {}
                },
        beforeShow: function()
        {
            console.log('beforeShow');
            // var obj = $(currentArray[currentIndex]); // from prev. version
            // if (obj.next().length) return obj.next().html(); // from prev. version
        }
    });
});
```

I tried this but don't know how to get the variables as index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use callbacks to update title, example:

```
$(".photogalleryLightbox li a").fancybox({
        beforeLoad : function() {
            this.title = 'My Custom Title';
        },
        helpers: { 
            title: {
                type: 'inside',
                beforeShow: function(opts) {
                    console.log('beforeShow title helper');
                },
            },
            buttons : {}
        },
        beforeShow: function() {
            console.log('beforeShow');
            // var obj = $(currentArray[currentIndex]); // from prev. version
            // if (obj.next().length) return obj.next().html(); // from prev. version
        }
    });
```

Comment: I fixed it like this:

`beforeShow: function()
  {
   // Get rich titles
   var currentElement = this.element;
   var next = $(currentElement).next();
   if(next.length && next.hasClass('caption')) this.title = next.html();
   //var currentIndex = this.index;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

I have added image-numbers to the title like this:

```
beforeShow : function() {
  this.title = '<span class="imgNo">Bild ' + (this.index + 1) + ' von ' + this.group.length + '</span>' + (this.title ? '' + this.title + '' : '');
}
```

This works great but the calculation of sizes and offsets of div.fancybox-wrap goes wrong:
With my image-numbers every image has a title in the lightbox, but not all of them get a 'real' title from the thumbnails title-tag.
But the sizes are calculated only with those 'real' titles.

Adding the image-numbers in `beforeLoad()` works too but with the same problem.

Has anybody an idea how to fix the calculation?
I haven't found it in the fancybox-code yet, so I could fix it there but I would prefer to do it in a callback function and not by changing the source code.