# Fancybox 2.0 title options

Tags: fancybox

In Fancybox 1.3.4 there were title options, like `TitlePosition`, `TitleFormat`.  Are there replacements for these options?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer: [Fancybox v2 override/format title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225416/fancybox-v2-override-format-title)

You need to use the beforeLoad() function to load a custom title element -

```
   $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    openEasing : 'easeOutBack',

    closeEffect : 'elastic',
    closeEasing : 'easeInBack',

    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    },
    beforeLoad : function() {
        this.title = 'My Custom Title';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

may this helps:

```
$("a[rel=group]").fancybox({
            openEffect      : 'fade',
            closeEffect     : 'fade',
            nextEffect      : 'fade',
            prevEffect      : 'fade',
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                }

            },
            beforeShow : function(opt) {
            if(this.element.title==''){
                this.element.title='Image '+ (this.index + 1) + ' / ' + this.group.length;
                this.title=this.element.title;
            }
        }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

its the same in 2.0 as well, check out the api: http://fancybox.net/api